# C# DateTime to EventDateTime

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

Currently I'm working with the v3 google calendar API. I have a specification which the local object needs to use dateTime, but google uses EventDateTime. I just wonder if there is a clever way to convert one to the other? I know it is possible to use tostring, but currently I have a hard time figuring out what prefixes I need to do so.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: string datetimeString = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), and then parse that as a EventDateTimeObject.setDate(datetimeString) or something along those lines.

Comment: That would not work if you want timed in hours and minutes though?

Comment: It doesn't mention hours and minutes in the docs as I can see (given I found the right one), but you could do a ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

Comment: I have answered this refer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142638/google-calendar-api-v3-eventdatetime/19630965#19630965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/EventDateTime.html) it is possible to use a string formatted datetime.

```
 setDate
 public EventDateTime setDate(DateTime date)
 The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
 Parameters:
 date - date or null for none
```

Sample:

```
 DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now();
 string dateTimeString = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

For the google calendar, your would probably create a EventDateTime object, and then set the date using the setDate(string datetime) method.

```
 EventDateTime eventDateTime = new EventDateTime();
 eventDateTime.setDate(dateTimeString);
```

To use a full day eventdatetime, you will omit the "HH:mm" from the ToString() method. I have never used this API, so something may be a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help someone...building on scheien's answer above.

Im just gonna post all the code..as it might help someone messing with Google Calender.

I have Method Extension that converts DateTime to EventDateTime.

Example from code

```
 evntNew.Start = oCalEvent.Start.ToEventDateTime();
```

Here the whole source. (feel free to edit)

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace GoogleCalendarAPI

{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly,
                                   CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents,
                                    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar};

        static string ApplicationName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CalendarEvent oCalEvent = new CalendarEvent();
            oCalEvent.Summary = "Hello Calendar";
            oCalEvent.Description = "Just another day";
            oCalEvent.Location = "Earth";
            oCalEvent.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31);
            oCalEvent.Stop = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31);
            AddCalendarEvent(oCalEvent);
            ListUpComing();

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void ListUpComing()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "admin",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void AddCalendarEvent(CalendarEvent oCalEvent)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "admin",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()   
            { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = ApplicationName, });              // Create Google Calendar API service.

            Event evntNew = new Event();
            evntNew.Summary = oCalEvent.Summary;
            evntNew.Location = oCalEvent.Location;
            evntNew.Description = oCalEvent.Description;
            evntNew.Start = oCalEvent.Start.ToEventDateTime();
            evntNew.End = oCalEvent.Stop.ToEventDateTime();
            EventsResource.InsertRequest insertRequest = service.Events.Insert(evntNew, "primary");
            insertRequest.Execute();
        }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static EventDateTime ToEventDateTime(this DateTime dDateTime)
    {
        EventDateTime edtDateTime = new EventDateTime();
        edtDateTime.DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", null);
        return edtDateTime;
    }

}
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public CalendarEvent() { }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
}

// END
```