# Timing issue when add the event to Google Calendar Event using C#?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

when i add events to google calendar service URL ,event can add without any mistake but when event insert into google calendar it show different time, why it shows different time,any one help me to resolve this issue ,i am giving my code below.

```
            string location = "India Standard Time";
            string sdate = "5/12/2016 09:00:00 AM";
            string edate =  "5/12/2016 09:15:00 AM";
            string descri = "Sample";
            string sumary = "Sample";

            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(sdate);
            DateTime? end = Convert.ToDateTime(edate);

            var dates = start.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            if (end.HasValue && end > start)
            {
                dates += "/" + end.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            }
            else
            {
                dates += "/" + start.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            }

            string what = descri;
            string websiteName = descri;
            string websiteAddress = "****************************";

            string path = string.Format("http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text={0}&dates={1}&details={2}&location={3}&trp=false&sprop={4}&sprop=name:{5}",
                                    what,
                                    dates,
                                    sumary,
                                    location,
                                    websiteName,
                                    websiteAddress);
```

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: It sounds like you are not passing the correct timezone. The Z in your toString means this will be in UTC. The location field is not the right place for timezone, it should be in the tz parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the time zone. You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) on how to set/use the timezone on your code.

Also check this related SO questions:

- [Google Calendar API v3 time zone issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519285/google-calendar-api-v3-time-zone-issues)
- [Google Calendar Api v3 EventDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142638/google-calendar-api-v3-eventdatetime)

Comment: Karthik is not using Calendar API, instead the templating web UI feature, which has slightly different parameters.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable information, I got the solution.

Comment: how did u solve @karthik