# Google Calendar API wrong time in calendar

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API v3 (C#) to insert events into a users calendar. I am sending an event like this.

```
{
   "AnyoneCanAddSelf":null,
   "Attendees":null,
   "AttendeesOmitted":null,
   "ColorId":null,
   "CreatedRaw":null,
   "Created":null,
   "Creator":null,
   "Description":"Electrolysis 1",
   "End":{
      "Date":null,
      "DateTimeRaw":"2020-09-16T11:15:00.000Z",
      "DateTime":"2020-09-16T11:15:00.0000000+00:00",
      "TimeZone":"Europe/London",
      "ETag":null,
      "_typeTag":"EventDateTime"
   },
   "EndTimeUnspecified":null,
   "ETag":null,
   "ExtendedProperties":null,
   "Gadget":null,
   "GuestsCanInviteOthers":null,
   "GuestsCanModify":null,
   "GuestsCanSeeOtherGuests":null,
   "HangoutLink":null,
   "HtmlLink":null,
   "ICalUID":null,
   "Id":null,
   "Kind":null,
   "Location":null,
   "Locked":null,
   "Organizer":null,
   "OriginalStartTime":null,
   "PrivateCopy":null,
   "Recurrence":null,
   "RecurringEventId":null,
   "Reminders":null,
   "Sequence":null,
   "Source":null,
   "Start":{
      "Date":null,
      "DateTimeRaw":"2020-09-16T11:00:00.000Z",
      "DateTime":"2020-09-16T11:00:00.0000000+00:00",
      "TimeZone":"Europe/London",
      "ETag":null,
      "_typeTag":"EventDateTime"
   },
   "Status":null,
   "Summary":"Ann Smith",
   "Transparency":null,
   "UpdatedRaw":null,
   "Updated":null,
   "Visibility":null
}
```

When the event is shown in the Google Calendar it shows up at 12pm, not 11am as would be expected. I assume it is Time Zone related but the calendar time zone is the same as the one I am passing through.

Here is a screenshot of what the time zone is set in Google Calendar.

[image: Google Calendar Timezone]

Comment: The timezone specified in `DateTime` might override the `TimeZone` property? Docu says `TimeZone` is optional unless the `DateTime` does not specify the timezone

Comment: @BiesiGrr I found _"A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone."_ Unfortunately, it doesn't say what happens if both is present _and_ different from each other.

Comment: Some things you could try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630965/982149, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520811/982149, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36323047/982149 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57115942/982149